# Generate dynamic URL pages basis filter options in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, url-routing

We have a rails app at [remote.tools](https://remote.tools) and if you see the product pages (see [this page](https://www.remote.tools/product/remoco)), there are a set of tags associated with each product. I am planning on having filtered search basis these tags on category pages (see [this page](https://www.remote.tools/category/video-conferencing-apps-for-remote-work)). Now, I have already tried doing this with the 'Acts-as-taggable' gem and 'Simple-form' (basis [this blog](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-a-smart-filter-for-your-rails-5-application-using-simple-form-and-acts-as-tattable-afac128e4159)).

I am fine with having a page refresh on hitting 'search' or doing it in place (able to do both right now). However, I want to have unique URLs to be created basis the combination of filters applied by the user. For example, if the user selects 'Video communication tools' as the category and 'free trial' and 'easy-to-use' as the tags, the page URL should be '/video-communication-tools-with-free-trial-that-are-easy-to-use'. Currently, the filter options are passed as params i.e. '/search?category=xx&tags=yy'.

Having separate URLs for filter combinations will allow me create unique pages for indexing and add content contextually as well.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: But why its necessary to pass the data in the URL, instead of that, use POST request and pass data in parameters.

Comment: Right. But the problem isn't with passing data, rather generating dynamic URLs basis the data.

Comment: does that dynamic URL wil be used once?

Comment: I am looking to mimic the behaviour on this page - https://nomadlist.com/affordable-places-in-europe. If you try the filters, you will see the URL changes and each combination is a new page.

Comment: Quite frankly I don't believe in the idea as you would have to dynamically generate a huge list of routes for every possible combination of categories / tags or use a completely nuts regex catch-all and then try to parse out categories and tags from `/video-communication-tools-with-free-trial-that-are-easy-to-use`. Whoever requested the feature overlooked how complex this is and that its completely pointless if you have extremely long vanity urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to achieve that,

Something like this.

```
<script>
    $('#search_button').on('click', function(){
            window.location = "" + $('#tag1').val()+"-"+$('#tag2').val();
        });
</script>
```

Make sure to add id in your search button. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. But there's a default way form submission is done by simple_form. Will I have to override that?

Comment: Yes, you may want to remove the default way of submitting the form, just remove the submit tag and add custom submit button with an id and use the above code, it will do the job.